# equivalence of Theano.tensor.ivector of Theano in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, theano

I am new in Tensorflow and Theano.

What is the equivalence Theano.tensor.ivector in Tensorflow?

For instance,

```
x = Theano.tensor.ivector('x')
y = Theano.tensor.ivector('y')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand, something like this would be equivalent:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.Variable([1, -2, 3], tf.int32, name='x')
```

you can find some additional information about theano and tensorflow variables in the following links (thanks [bouteillebleu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/300977/bouteillebleu)):

http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html
https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/dims_types

---

If you are using these as inputs and you don't know the initial contents, you have to use placeholders:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, name='x')
```

Comment: Based on http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html (for Theano data types) and https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/dims_types (for Tensorflow data types), that looks right. (Worth linking those in your post?)

Comment: But the thing I didn't understand, x doesn't exist. It is the first time x is created with the functions I have written in my question. How do I know what is the content of x, and the dimension?

Comment: I see. I am updating the answer.

Comment: @bouteillebleu I added the links as your suggested. Thanks!